# Xamarin Android Spinner not showing

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a fragment where I want to have google map and two spinners to choose a car number and a day. Do you know why my spinners does not show ? When I am looking in axml file they show, but when I run the app on my phone, only the map shows. What am I missing?

**This is may .axml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRefreshData"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Car number"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerCar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:margin_left="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtRefreshData"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtspinnerDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Day"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spinnerCar"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtspinnerDate"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_placeholder"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**Where is drawed with red, the spinners should show.**
[image]

**This is my .cs**

```
     GoogleMap map;
        MapFragment mapFragment;
        List<LatLng> markers = new List<LatLng>();
        List<string> carnumbers = new List<string>();
        MarkerOptions markerOptions;
        TextView txtRefreshData;

        public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            int ct = 1;
            if (markers.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in markers)
                {
                    map = googleMap;
                    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.SetPosition(item);
                    markerOptions.SetTitle("My Position" + ct);
                    map.AddMarker(markerOptions);
                    ct++;
                }
                FitAllMarkers(map);
            }
        }
        private void FitAllMarkers(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

            foreach (LatLng item in markers)
            {
                builder.Include(item);
            }

            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.Build();
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngBounds(bounds, 100);

            googleMap.AnimateCamera(cu);
        }
        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            mapFragment = MapFragment.NewInstance();
            var ft = Activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            ft.Add(Resource.Id.map_placeholder, mapFragment).Commit();
            mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
        }
        public async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.LiveTrackingAdminFragment, container, false);
            this.Activity.Title = "Live Tracking";

Spinner spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinnerCar);
Spinner spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinnerDay);

            return view;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I) In your first TableRow, set the height of the RelativeLayout with a fixed size, such as `android:layout_height="50dp"`

II) In `spinnerCar`, remove `android:margin_left`, it's not valid and may cause errors

III) In each spinner (`spinnerCar` and `spinnerDate`) set a fixed width, with `android:layout_width="120dp"` for example